# Reading Firebase Database and Show In RecyclerView : Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This is my code:

**Liste.java file:**

```
public class Liste extends AppCompatActivity{

    RecyclerView myRecyclerview;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    List<Dentist> listDentist;
    FirebaseDatabase FDB;
    DatabaseReference DBR;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_liste );

        myRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.myRecycler );
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager LM = new LinearLayoutManager ( getApplicationContext ());
        myRecyclerview.setLayoutManager ( LM );
        myRecyclerview.setItemAnimator ( new DefaultItemAnimator () );
        myRecyclerview.addItemDecoration ( new DividerItemDecoration ( getApplicationContext (),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ) );

        listDentist = new ArrayList<> (  );

        adapter = new MyAdapter (listDentist);

        FDB= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
        GetDataFirebase();

 void GetDataFirebase(){
        DBR = FDB.getReference ("dentistes");

        DBR.addChildEventListener ( new ChildEventListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Dentist data = dataSnapshot.getValue (Dentist.class);
                //Add to Arraylist
                listDentist.add ( data );
                //Add list into adapter
                myRecyclerview.setAdapter ( adapter );


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

        List<Dentist> listArray;

        public MyAdapter (List<Dentist> List){
            this.listArray = List;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext ()).inflate ( R.layout.itemview,parent,false );
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Dentist data = listArray.get ( position );
            holder.MyText.setText ( data.getName () );
        }
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView MyText;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super ( itemView );
                MyText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.textview_dentist );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listArray.size ();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_liste.xml file**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/myRecycler">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**iteview.xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textview_dentist"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**My class model:**

```
public class Dentist {
    private String Name;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

- The list of dentists is correctly displayed in my Recyclerview but the logcat shows me"E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout":how can i correct this?
- If i change the stucture of my class model :for example i add address and TelNumber :how i should change my code in order to show foreach Dentist in my Recyclerview his Name, Adress and NumTel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, please see my answers below:

1. Move this line of code

   ```
   adapter = new MyAdapter(listDentist);
   ```

Inside `onChildAdded()` method. Your adapter must be declared and used inside this method.

2. You need to change your `Dentist` class by adding those private fields and by adding the corresponding public setter and getters.

Comment: 1- The message " E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout " is always displayed in the log cat.                                                                            2- I know that i shoud adding those private fields to the Dentist class but i'm blocked in how i should change the code in the Liste.java file.

Comment: Make sure that you are calling that statement from the "main" thread, in onChildAdded() method. And there is the only place you are doing this. Also declare the `myRecyclerview` also inside that method. Does it work now?

Comment: The list of dentists is correctly displayed in my Recyclerview but the logcat shows this Error again: but it's not a problem.                                                         I need an answer for my second question.

Comment: As answered you earlier, first you need to change your model class and then loop through the childrens of each dentist to get the data. It's ok now?

Comment: What was wrong with my answer? Please provide me an explanation.

Comment: @ Alex Mamo:Sorry What answer ? i don't understand you ?

Comment: This answer that i have provided you. Why did you changed the accepted answer? What was wrong with my answer?

Comment: @Nesrine Thanks!

Comment: I'm so so so sorry ,Really i'm sorry,perhaps that was inattention action.On the contrary your Answer was helpful.I'm so sorry again.

Comment: Really i'm sorry @Alex Mamo : i'm beginner in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warning in logcat,set the adapter in your onCreate method and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in  your onChildAdded method to update values...

```
    public class Liste extends AppCompatActivity{

    RecyclerView myRecyclerview;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    List<Dentist> listDentist;
    FirebaseDatabase FDB;
    DatabaseReference DBR;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_liste );

        myRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.myRecycler );
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager LM = new LinearLayoutManager ( getApplicationContext ());
        myRecyclerview.setLayoutManager ( LM );
        myRecyclerview.setItemAnimator ( new DefaultItemAnimator () );
        myRecyclerview.addItemDecoration ( new DividerItemDecoration ( getApplicationContext (),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL ) );

        listDentist = new ArrayList<> (  );

        adapter = new MyAdapter (listDentist);

       //Set empty adapter here
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FDB= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
        GetDataFirebase();

 void GetDataFirebase(){
        DBR = FDB.getReference ("dentistes");

        DBR.addChildEventListener ( new ChildEventListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Dentist data = dataSnapshot.getValue (Dentist.class);
                //Add to Arraylist
                listDentist.add ( data );
                //Add list into adapter


               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

        List<Dentist> listArray;

        public MyAdapter (List<Dentist> List){
            this.listArray = List;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext ()).inflate ( R.layout.itemview,parent,false );
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Dentist data = listArray.get ( position );
            holder.MyText.setText ( data.getName () );
        }
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView MyText;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super ( itemView );
                MyText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById ( R.id.textview_dentist );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listArray.size ();
        }
    }
}
```

And for your second question as mentioned by Alex Mamo you need to add fields you want and corresponding getters and setters in your Dentist class.